# How to combine two firebase collections into a new array of objects

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, rxjs, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on a small project with Angular and Firebase. When a date is changed I need to get a list of "Questions" that have been created, on or before that date as well as a single "Answer" of that Question for that day.

The current date is a BehaviorSubject so when it changes I use a switchmap to get the list of Questions and Answers for that date.

But it seems after using forkJoin and map to combine/merge the two array's into one nothing is displayed on my page. But if I simply return the QuestionsCollection before I forkJoin, I get the list of questions, but that doesn't help because I still won't have the Answer for that Question on that Date.

So returning only the const q, before the forkJoin will result in.
a list of Questions like the below (that answer property is a default because if I don't have one I from the database I instantiate a new one for the user which will be added once they save their score), but using the forkJoin, doesn't even return an []

```
[
 {
"id": "e0gdRmeNu2bheekeyT6m",
"uid": "uPhcLZkaRYRXpsSZC0zbRqUOWOq2",
"question": "Combine Q with A",
"goal": 10,
"answer": {
  "id": null,
  "score": null,
  "qid": null,
},
...
]
```

In firebase Answers and Questions are separate collections, because the user will only ever have 1 answer per day I don't want to get all previous answers when I ask for Questions for a Date.

**Main Method**

```
getQuestions() {
    //Observable<Question[]>
    this.questions = this.dateService.dateStore
        .pipe(
            switchMap(date => {
                const startDate = moment(date).startOf('day').utc().toDate();
                const endDate = moment(date).endOf('day').utc().toDate();

                //Observable<Question[]>
                const q = this.getQuestionsUntilDate(endDate);
                //Observable<Answer[]>
                const a = this.getAnswersForDateRange(startDate, endDate);

                //forkjoin and map results together?
                //doesn't seem to work
                return forkJoin([q, a])
                    .pipe(
                        map(val => {
                            let questions = val[0];
                            let answers = val[1];

                            questions.forEach(question => {
                                //a answer is not guaranteed to exist so only
                                //add it to the question if we found one.
                                const answer = answers.find(answer => answer.qid === question.id);
                                if (answer) {
                                    question.answer = answer;
                                }
                            });

                            return questions;
                        }));
            }))
}
```

**Question and Answers Collection calls**

```
    private getQuestionsUntilDate(date: Date) {
    return this.qCollection(ref => ref
        .where('timestamp', '<=', date)
        .where('uid', '==', this.auth.userId)
        .orderBy('timestamp'))
        .snapshotChanges()
        .pipe(
            map(res => {
                return res.map(q => {
                    return new Question({
                        id: q.payload.doc.id,
                        ...q.payload.doc.data()
                    })
                })
            })
        );
}

private getAnswersForDateRange(sDate: Date, eDate: Date) {
    return this.aCollection(ref => ref
        .where('timestamp', '<=', eDate)
        .where('timestamp', '>=', sDate)
        .where('uid', '==', this.auth.userId))
        .snapshotChanges()
        .pipe(
            map(res => {
                return res.map(a => {
                    return new Answer({
                        id: a.payload.doc.id,
                        ...a.payload.doc.data(),
                    })
                })
            })
        );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`forkJoin` will emit last values from given observables when all these observables **complete**.

[image: forkJoin marble diagram]

And it seems like `snapshotChanges()` returns you an Observable that won't complete with emitting first values.

So try substituting [`forkJoin`](https://thinkrx.io/rxjs/forkJoin/) with a [`zip`](https://thinkrx.io/rxjs/zip/), for example.

`zip` will let you combine values from the observables in order of emission: 1st value with 1st value, 2nd with 2nd, etc.

If you need to react on updates from any of the streams — try [`combineLatest`](https://thinkrx.io/rxjs/combineLatest/).

***NOTE***: you'll need to import `zip` from `rxjs`, not `rxjs/operators`

Comment: I had to use combineLatest, but this worked. Thank you!