# How to make an inner join in the Firestore database with the AngularFireBase library?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, ionic4, angularfire

I currently have 2 collections, one is called "cart" and contains a list of product IDs and the second is called "products", what I want to achieve is to obtain a single list that includes all the data and products that the user already added to Your shopping cart

I have a couple of days looking for some way to make the "internal union" but I have not had much success and the information I find is already more than 1 year, I leave some links of the information i read

https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/firestore-joins-similar-to-sql/
https://angularfirebase.com/snippets/combine-firestore-collections-into-a-single-array-observable/

For now I have the cart list, which contains the products that the user agreed.

```
cart
  KeyFirestore1
    [0]
      id_product:product1
    [1]
      id_product:product2
```

And the list of products

```
products
  product1
    name:"apple"
    price:20.00
    id_product:"product1"
  product2
    nombre:"ice cream"
    price:40.00
    id_product:"product2"
```

and I would like to only get only one list when consulting

```
cart_products
  KeyFirestore1
    [0]
      name:"apple"
      price:20.00
      id_product:"product1"
    [1]
      name:"ice cream"
      price:40.00
      id_product:"product2"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do that, you shall use forkJoin. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55548133/11928130) explains how to implement it.

As mentioned in the answer, "If you need to react on updates from any of the streams — try combineLatest."

Here are more details about [combineLatest operator](https://thinkrx.io/rxjs/combineLatest/) and a [full example](https://medium.com/@joaqcid/how-to-inner-join-data-from-multiple-collections-on-angular-firebase-bfd04f6b36b7) (please read the second scenario).